# mocking a class: catch 22

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

### brief summary

`MyClass.my_method` has a call to `instance = SomeLibrary()`  I want to create a mock so `instance` is a mocked object that I can control.  In the spirit of isolated testing, I don't actually want to call into `SomeLibrary`.

### what argument to pass to `@mock.patch()`

I'm trying to mock the class constructor, but I haven't figured out what to pass to the @mock.patch() decorator.  The docs say that the argument must be fully dotted (`pyftdi.ftdi.Ftdi`), but the `where to patch` docs say that the argument must match the name by which the code being tested knows it (`Ftdi`).  I don't see how to satisfy both.

To make it concrete, here's the file being tested:

```
from pyftdi.ftdi import Ftdi

class FtdiInterface(object):
    @classmethod
    def set_power(cls, url, on):
        ftdi = Ftdi()
        ftdi.open_from_url(url)
        # ... do other things with ftdi
```

... and the test file

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from ftdi_interface import FtdiInterface
import pyftdi.ftdi

class TestFtdiInterface(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('pyftdi.ftdi.Ftdi')
    def testPowerOn(self, MockFtdi):
        url = 'some_string'
        ftdi_instance = mock.MagicMock()
        ftdi_instance.open_from_url = mock.MagicMock()
        MockFtdi.return_value = ftdi_instance

        FtdiInterface.set_power(url, True)
        ftdi_instance.open_from_url.assert_called_with(url)
```

What I observe is that, despite my attempt to patch Ftdi(), the call to `ftdi_instance.open_from_url()` calls the library code, not my mocked object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?#where-to-patch) states:

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

It means that to `mock` a class `Ftdi` you have to provide a path to the place in your code where `Ftdi` is actually instantiated.

To do so you you need to replace `@mock.patch('pyftdi.ftdi.Ftdi')` with `@mock.patch('ftdi_interface.Ftdi')`:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from ftdi_interface import FtdiInterface

class TestFtdiInterface(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('ftdi_interface.Ftdi')
    def testPowerOn(self, MockFtdi):
        url = 'some_string'
        ftdi_instance = mock.MagicMock()
        ftdi_instance.open_from_url = mock.MagicMock()
        MockFtdi.return_value = ftdi_instance

        FtdiInterface.set_power(url, True)
        ftdi_instance.open_from_url.assert_called_with(url)
```

Line `import pyftdi.ftdi` doesn't make anything useful for test and can be dropped.

Comment: Doh!  I must have read that sentence in `where to patch` a dozen times, but it wasn't until I saw your answer that I fully understood its implications.  Thanks -- worked!